# How to pass multiple lines into interpreter?

Tags: python, ptvs

I'm not sure how to phrase the question another way, but I upgraded from VS 13' to 15', and I'm no longer able to run multiple statements in the REPL window. I get 'SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement'. I know in 13' i was able to run multiple lines/statements with error. Any suggestions?

Comment: This might be a crappy workaround for you but have you tried using semicolons as line terminators? These are optional in Python but they do work. Also, if there's something that integrates iPython into VS, you could use its 'magic' `%paste` command for this.

Comment: Im thinking it must be some option in the settings. Just dont know why it'd change with a software upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Sending it to the interactive works. Still new to VS and PTVS, so kind of a bonehead move.